# Different Measures On R2 

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

Dear all,

Is there any possible way to construct a set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n $ for which $ H^{n-1} (\partial A) > Leb^ + (A ) $?

Where $ H^{n-1} (\partial A) $ is the Hausdorff measure of the boundary of $A$ and:
$ Leb^{+} (A) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0 } \frac{ Leb(A_ \epsilon) - Leb(A) }{\epsilon} $ , 
$A_\epsilon := \{ x \in \mathbb{R} ^n | d(x,A) \leq \epsilon \} $ =Minkowski's content with respect to Lebesgue measure.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: פ.ת.ףץפתך.80פת. 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, $A$ is just a "set"?  Say $A$ is an open square minus a mid-line:
$$
A = \{ (x,y): 0 \lt x \lt 1 \text{ and (} 0 \lt y \lt 1/2 \text{ or } 1/2 \lt y \lt 1\text{)}\}
$$
Then $\partial A$ consists of 5 line-segments of length $1$ (the 4 sides and the mid-line), so $H^1(\partial A) = 5$.  But $\mathrm{Leb}^+(A) = 4$, missing the mid-line.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! The problem is that I can't understand the calculation of such thing: 
By definition  :
$H^1 ( \partial A) = lim _{\delta \to 0} inf \{ \sum C diam(U_i) |
\partial A \subseteq \cup U_i , diam(U_i ) \leq \delta \} $
Can you please detail a bit about how you deduced that $H^1 (\partial A) = 5$ in this case?

Thanks a lot @!  

Comment: First: For a line segment of length $a$, the one-dimensional Hausdorff measure is $a$.  Hausdorff measure is additive on Borel sets, so the measure for the 5-segment set is $5$.