# Geometric Measure Theory On Euclidean Spaces

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

Dear all,

I have recently found the following discussion:
[Different Measures On R2](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/102061/hausdorff-measure-and-minkowskis-content-boundary-measures) 
regarding different boundary measures on $\mathbb{R}^n $ .

The discussion made me wondering:

Is there any example in the opposite direction?

i.e. an example of a set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R} ^n $ such that $ Leb^+ (A) > H^{n-1} (\partial A) $ ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $[0,1]\times \{0\} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Dear @Tapio:
Thanks for your answer, but I don't think I understand it:
We have $H^1(\partial [0,1]\times0 )=H^1([0,1]\times0 ) = 1 $ .
But I can't understand how to calculate the minkowski's content of this thing- $Leb ( [0,1] \times 0 ) = 0 $ since we are in $\mathbb{R}^2 $ . But what is the Lebesgue measure of an $\epsilon$ extension of this thing?

Thanks ! 

Comment: @Jeremy, $\mathop{Leb}^+=2$.

Comment: @Anton: Can you please explain this calculation?
Thanks! 

Comment: @Jeremy: An $\epsilon$ extension of that set is very simple, and the computation of its area is completely elementary.  Just draw a picture of it.

Comment: @Mark: I agree that an $\epsilon$ extension of this set is pretty simple to calculate in the $\mathbb{R} $ case (and it's equal to $2\epsilon$ there indeed, which gives $Leb^+ =2 $ as you said. 
But since we're looking at the $\mathbb{R}^2 $ case, the $\epsilon$ extension we are looking at is actually some kind of an ellipse, which I have no idea how to calculate its volume. 
I hope I made my misunderstandings clear now.

Thanks a lot ! 

Comment: @Jeremy: It's not an ellipse: it's a rectangle plus two semicircles.

Answer (score 4):

$A=\mathbb{Z}\subset \mathbb R^2$. In this case $\partial\mathbb{Z}= \mathbb{Z}$ and
$\mathop{Leb}^+(\mathbb Z)=\infty$ and $H^1(\mathbb Z)=0$.

You can get a bounded example of the same type. 
Take a countable nowhere dense set $A$ in the unit disc such that the $\varepsilon$-neighborhood of $A$ contains a disc of radius $\sqrt[3]{\varepsilon}$.

Comment: But $\partial \mathbb{Q} = \mathbb{R}$. Perhaps you mean $\mathop{Leb}^+(\mathbb Z)=\infty$ and $H^1(\mathbb Z)=0$?

Comment: Ups, you are right, now it is corrected.

Comment: Thanks @Anton, but I was thinking about this question in the context of boundary measures...In this case, since $\partial \mathbb{Z} $ is empty , it doesn't give me an answer.

Thanks anyway! 

Comment: @Jeremy, $\partial \mathbb Z=\mathbb Z$.

Comment: yes. you are right... sorry and thank you very much!
